# Hibernate bean in Spring fails to load throwing java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, spring-mvc

I am very new in Spring 4.2.3. I stuck in configuring Hibernate 4.3.11 in my Spring project.
Following are the error stack trace for my project configuration

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AutoProxyUtils.determineTargetClass(Lorg/springframework/beans/factory/config/ConfigurableListableBeanFactory;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Class;
at org.springframework.context.event.EventListenerMethodProcessor.afterSingletonsInstantiated(EventListenerMethodProcessor.java:78)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:792)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:838)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
at me.shafin.sustord.dao.App.main(App.java:8)
```

**App.java**

```
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class App {

public static void main(String[] args) {
     ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring/dao-config.xml");
     CourseDaoImpl dao = (CourseDaoImpl) context.getBean("CourseDao");
     System.err.println(dao.list().size());
     context.close();        
}
}
```

**dao-config.xml**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.2.xsd">

<bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/shafin_sustord" />
    <property name="user" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="password" />

    <!-- these are C3P0 properties -->
    <property name="acquireIncrement" value="5" />
    <property name="minPoolSize" value="1" />
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="100" />
    <property name="maxIdleTime" value="1800" />
</bean>


<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            <!--<prop key="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCacheProvider</prop>-->
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="packagesToScan">
        <list>
            <value>me.shafin.sustord.entity</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<context:component-scan base-package="me.shafin.sustord.dao"></context:component-scan>
<context:annotation-config />
<tx:annotation-driven />
```

**CourseDaoImpl.java**

```
package me.shafin.sustord.dao;

import java.util.List;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import me.shafin.sustord.model.Course;

@Component("courseDao")
public class CourseDaoImpl implements CourseDao {

private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

@Autowired
public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
}

public List<Course> list() {
    Session session = this.sessionFactory.openSession();
    List<Course> list = session.createQuery("from Course").list();
    session.close();
    return list;
    }

}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<properties>

    <!-- Generic properties -->
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

    <!-- Web -->
    <jsp.version>2.3.1</jsp.version>
    <jstl.version>1.2</jstl.version>
    <servlet.version>3.1.0</servlet.version>


    <!-- Spring -->
    <spring-framework.version>4.2.3.RELEASE</spring-framework.version>
    <spring-security.version>4.0.3.RELEASE</spring-security.version>

    <!-- Hibernate -->
    <hibernate-framework.version>4.3.11.Final</hibernate-framework.version>

    <!-- Validator -->
    <hibernate.validator.version>5.1.2.Final</hibernate.validator.version>
    <javax.validation.version>1.1.0.Final</javax.validation.version>

    <!-- Logging -->
    <logback.version>1.0.13</logback.version>
    <slf4j.version>1.7.5</slf4j.version>

    <!-- Test -->
    <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>

</properties>

<dependencies>

    <!-- Spring MVC -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- Spring security -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring and Transactions -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>



    <!-- Hibernate -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate-framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.37</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
        <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>c3p0</groupId>
        <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jaxen</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxen</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.6</version>
    </dependency>



    <!-- jsr303 validation dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>${javax.validation.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.validator.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Other Web dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>${jstl.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>${servlet.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>${jsp.version}</version>
    </dependency>




    <!-- Logging with SLF4J & LogBack -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>


    <!-- Test Artifacts -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.modelgen.processor</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsr250-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<groupId>me.shafin.sustord</groupId>
<artifactId>sust-ord</artifactId>
```

I am desperately begging a solution of this silly problem that causes my 2 days in vein. Pardon

Comment: At which line exactly is your exception being thrown? I can not seem to find it Shafin

Comment: Its being thrown from `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring/dao-config.xml");` in App.java

Comment: Could it be for compatibility issue with Spring and Hibernate version @YassinHajaj ??

Comment: Why do you have Hibernate and Eclipselink on your classpath? You should choose only one JPA implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved the issue. It was actually for Hibernate and Spring version compatibility problem. I switched the dependency to `Spring 4.0.6` and `Hibernate 4.0.3` and it work like magic :) and obviously thanx to @dunni for pointing to the redundant dependency. actually that came from default project setup.