# spring-webmvc 4.2.3 and 4.2.2 incompatible?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am experimenting with Spring Security. The built-in login page can be displayed with:

- spring-webmvc-4.2.**2**.RELEASE
- spring-security-core-4.0.3.RELEASE

This is the `good` combination of jars:

[image: This is the good combination of jars]

But when I change to:

- spring-webmvc-4.2.**3**.RELEASE
- spring-security-core-4.0.3.RELEASE

This is the `failed`combination of jars:

[image: This is the failed combination of jars]

I encountered the following error when starting the tomcat. How could this minor change be **in-compatible**?

My pom.xml is quite simple as below, I `only` specify the `org.springframework.version` and `org.springframework.security.version`, which are both the latest. And all the others are `transitive dependencies` which I totally `leave to Maven`.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>mygroup</groupId>
  <artifactId>mycloud-server</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <properties>
    <org.springframework.version>4.2.3.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
    <org.springframework.security.version>4.0.3.RELEASE</org.springframework.security.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>



  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>

  <build>
     <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <configuration>
            <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
         </plugin>

        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1</version>
          <configuration>
            <source>1.7</source>
            <target>1.7</target>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>

     </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

> Dec 08, 2015 12:04:26 AM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
>   **SEVERE: Context initialization failed** 
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AutoProxyUtils.determineTargetClass(Lorg/springframework/beans/factory/config/ConfigurableListableBeanFactory;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Class;
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.event.EventListenerMethodProcessor.afterSingletonsInstantiated(EventListenerMethodProcessor.java:78)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:792)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:838)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:446)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:328)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4770)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5196)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1399)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>
> Dec 08, 2015 12:04:26 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext
>   listenerStart **SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to
>   listener instance of class**
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AutoProxyUtils.determineTargetClass(Lorg/springframework/beans/factory/config/ConfigurableListableBeanFactory;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Class;
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.event.EventListenerMethodProcessor.afterSingletonsInstantiated(EventListenerMethodProcessor.java:78)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:792)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:838)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:446)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:328)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4770)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5196)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1399)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>
> Dec 08, 2015 12:04:26 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext
>   startInternal **SEVERE: Error listenerStart Dec 08, 2015 12:04:26 AM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal SEVERE: Context
>   [/mycloud-server] startup failed due to previous errors** Dec 08, 2015
>   12:04:26 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log INFO:
>   Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext Dec 08, 2015 12:04:26 AM
>   org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
>   doClose INFO: Closing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Tue
>   Dec 08 00:04:25 CST 2015]; root of context hierarchy Dec 08, 2015
>   12:04:26 AM
>   org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
>   doClose WARNING: Exception thrown from LifecycleProcessor on context
>   close java.lang.IllegalStateException: LifecycleProcessor not
>   initialized - call 'refresh' before invoking lifecycle methods via the
>   context: Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Tue Dec 08 00:04:25
>   CST 2015]; root of context hierarchy  at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getLifecycleProcessor(AbstractApplicationContext.java:414)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:972)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:931)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.closeWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:583)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextDestroyed(ContextLoaderListener.java:116)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4813)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5413)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:160)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1399)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: And its a version change of 2 points, not a small change. Also, ideally, one would use a specific Spring version and declare that in POM.xml and use it throughout directly.

Comment: I'm able to run with 4.2.3 and 4.0.3 with the BOM method in the `pom.xml`.  Are you sure it's not a hibernate compatibility issue?   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33845430/hibernate-bean-in-spring-fails-to-load-throwing-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror  (I'm working with 4.3.8.Final for Hibernate without issue)

Comment: You can have a look at this one too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34053170/spring-4-2-3-release-and-hibernate-5-0-4-final-compatibility-issue

Comment: You shouldn't upgrade a single jar you should upgrade all Spring jars to that version. Currently you are mixing different versions of spring which is never a good idea (for any framework btw).

Comment: @M.Deinum I add some details to my question. Actually I didn't modify only one jar. I let Maven to resolve the transitive dependencies.

Comment: @bphilipnyc, I didn't include hibernate in my project, yet.

Comment: @smwikipedia only partially as you only specify the webmvc dependency. Spring Security will pull in other dependencies which might conflict. Do `mvn dependency:tree` and check for conflicting jars. I suggest using the [spring io platform](http://docs.spring.io/platform/docs/2.0.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#getting-started-using-spring-io-platform-maven) as either a parent or dependency management feature. That way changing a version is simply a matter of changing a property.

Comment: @M.Deinum I got this notorious error: `Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.0.6 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): connect timed out` after adding this `    <parent>
        <groupId>io.spring.platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>platform-bom</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>  `

Comment: I solved the error `from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): connect timed out`  (here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25787197/error-shown-when-creating-new-maven-project-in-eclipse/34158764#34158764)  But the issue in this question remains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @M.Deinum's suggestion. I followed this [link](http://platform.spring.io/platform/#quick-start) to use the Spring IO Platform.

I encountered several strange issues during Maven update with my `10G` old local repository. [I solved it by using a new empty local repository.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25787197/error-shown-when-creating-new-maven-project-in-eclipse/34158764#34158764)

And it works. It's quite neat to use [maven dependency management](http://docs.spring.io/platform/docs/2.0.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#getting-started-using-spring-io-platform-maven).

My `pom.xml` now looks like this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>xxx</groupId>
    <artifactId>mycloud-server</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>


    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.spring.platform</groupId>
                <artifactId>platform-bom</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

And the so-called `managed dependency` are displayed as below:

[image]

### And some tips:

Based on my experience, many Maven errors are caused by failed download of dependencies or plugins. For each failed download, a `*.lastUpdated` file will be created. Sometimes this file will block a second download attempt. You can use the following commands to remove them.

1. cd to local repository.
2. run: `dir *.lastUpdated /s` to identify all of them.
3. run: `del *.lastUpdated /s` to remove all of them.
4. run: `Maven -> Update` in eclipse again.